# Optimizing a Summation function - GEKKO

Tags: optimization, gekko

I just started learning optimization and I have some issues finding the optimal value for the problem below. 
Note: This is just a random problem that came to my mind and has no real application.

Problem:

[image]

where `x` can be any value from the list ([2,4,6]) and `y` is between 1 and 3.

My attempt:

```python
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import math

def prob(x,y,sel):
    z = np.sum(np.array(x)*np.array(sel))
    cst = 0
    i=0
    while i <= y.VALUE:
        fact = 1
        for num in range(2, i + 1): # find the factorial value
            fact *= num
        cst += (z**i)/fact
        i+=1
    return cst


m = GEKKO(remote=False)

sel = [2,4,6] # list of possible x values
x =  m.Array(m.Var, 3, **{'value':1,'lb':0,'ub':1, 'integer': True})
y = m.Var(value=1,lb=1,ub=3,integer=True)

# switch to APOPT
m.options.SOLVER = 1

m.Equation(m.sum(x) == 1) # restrict choice to one selection

m.Maximize(prob(x,y,sel))
m.solve(disp=True)


print('Results:')
print(f'x: {x}')
print(f'y : {y.value}')
print('Objective value: ' + str(m.options.objfcnval))
```

Results:

```python
----------------------------------------------------------------
 APMonitor, Version 0.9.2
 APMonitor Optimization Suite
 ----------------------------------------------------------------


 --------- APM Model Size ------------
 Each time step contains
   Objects      :  0
   Constants    :  0
   Variables    :  4
   Intermediates:  0
   Connections  :  0
   Equations    :  2
   Residuals    :  2

 Number of state variables:    4
 Number of total equations: -  1
 Number of slack variables: -  0
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :    3

 ----------------------------------------------
 Steady State Optimization with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
Iter:     1 I:  0 Tm:     -0.00 NLPi:    2 Dpth:    0 Lvs:    0 Obj: -7.00E+00 Gap:  0.00E+00
 Successful solution

 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :  0.024000000000000004 sec
 Objective      :  -7.
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------


Results:
x: [[0.0] [0.0] [1.0]]
y : [1.0]
Objective value: -7.0
```

`x` should be [0,0,1] (i.e. 6) and `y` should be 3 to get the maximum value (61). `x` value I get is correct but for some reason the `y` value I get is wrong. What is causing this issue ? Is there something wrong with my formulation ? Also it would be very helpful if you could kindly point me towards more information about the various notations (like Tm, NLPi, etc) in APOPT solver output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution in gekko:

```
x=6.0
y=3.0
```

You'll need to use the gekko functions to build the functions and pose the problem in a way so that the equations don't change as the variable values change.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import factorial

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
x = m.sos1([2,4,6])
yb = m.Array(m.Var,3,lb=0,ub=1,integer=True)
m.Equation(m.sum(yb)==1)
y = m.sum([yb[i]*(i+1) for i in range(3)])
yf = factorial(np.linspace(0,3,4))
obj = x**0/yf[0]
for j in range(1,4):
    obj += x**j/yf[j]
    m.Maximize(yb[j-1]*obj)
m.solve()
print('x='+str(x.value[0]))
print('y='+str(y.value[0]))
print('Objective='+str(-m.options.objfcnval))
```

For your problem, I used a [Special Ordered Set (type 1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_ordered_set) to get the options of 2, 4, or 6. To select `y` as 1, 2, or 3 I calculated all possible values and then used a binary selector `yb` to choose one. There is a constraint that only one of them can be used with `m.sum(yb)==1`. There are [gekko examples](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/GekkoPythonOptimization), [documentation](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), and a [short course](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/ShortCourse) available if you need additional resources.
Here is the solver output:

```py
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 APMonitor, Version 0.9.2
 APMonitor Optimization Suite
 ----------------------------------------------------------------


 --------- APM Model Size ------------
 Each time step contains
   Objects      :  1
   Constants    :  0
   Variables    :  11
   Intermediates:  1
   Connections  :  4
   Equations    :  10
   Residuals    :  9

 Number of state variables:    11
 Number of total equations: -  7
 Number of slack variables: -  0
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :    4

 ----------------------------------------------
 Steady State Optimization with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
Iter:     1 I:  0 Tm:      0.00 NLPi:    6 Dpth:    0 Lvs:    0 Obj: -6.10E+01 Gap:  0.00E+00
 Successful solution

 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :  0.047799999999999995 sec
 Objective      :  -61.
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------


x=6.0
y=3.0
Objective=61.0
```

Here is more information on the [solver APOPT options](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/OptionApmSolver). The iteration summary describes the [branch and bound progress](https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/DiscreteOptimization). It is `Iter`=iteration number, `Tm`=time to solve the NLP, `NLPi`=NLP iterations, `Dpth`=depth in the branching tree, `Lvs`=number of candidates leaves, `Obj`=NLP solution objective, and `Gap`=gap between integer solution and best non-integer solution.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now. Even though this does give me the correct values for `x` and `y` , there is an issue in the Objective value (it is 36 instead of 61). It should be a summation of `i` =0  to `y` (as per problem description in question). But because of `yb`, only the value of `i` =`y` is taken. To fix it I added a for loop on top of your for loop.     
    `ans = 1
    for i in range(3):
        ans += m.sum([yb[j]*(x**(y-i))/yf[j] for j in range(len(yb))])
        yb = np.delete(yb,0)`
This seems to fix it. But not sure if there is a better way.

Comment: Thanks. I provided a new solution that gives the correct values for `x` and `y` as well as the objective function.

Comment: Your proposed changes are also good. One thing to watch out for is that even if you delete yb[0] from the list, that variable is still created in gekko. The variable doesn't influence the solution but it will be an extra value for the solver to calculate and may slow down the solution time if there are many of these deleted variables.

Answer (score 0):

[equation to be minimzed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEdRQ.png)hey how to solve these type of prolems

problem:

Minimization

> summation(xij*yij)

i=from 0 to 4000
j= from 0 to 100

y is coast matrix given

```
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
dem_var = m.Array(m.Var,(4096,100),lb=0)

for i,j in s_d:
   m.Minimize(sum([dem_var[i][j]*coast_new[i][j]]))
```

here y=coast_new
x= dem_var