# Optimizing Summation function with bounds from binary selector - GEKKO

Tags: python, optimization, gekko

I am trying to optimize a summation function. From a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61845226/optimizing-a-summation-function-gekko), I found half an answer for my problem(I have made my objective function similar to the one in that question).

Problem :

[image]

Attempt :

```python
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import factorial

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
x = m.sos1([1,2,3])
yb = m.Array(m.Var,3,lb=0,ub=1,integer=True)
m.Equation(m.sum(yb)==1)
y = m.sum([yb[i]*(i+1) for i in range(3)])
m.Equation(m.sum([yb[i]*(i+1) for i in range(3)])<2)
yf = factorial(np.linspace(0,len(yb),len(yb)+1))
obj = m.exp(x)
for j in range(0,len(yb)):
    obj += x**j/yf[j]
    m.Maximize(obj*yb[j])
m.solve()
print('x='+str(x.value[0]))
print('y='+str(y.value[0]))
print('Objective='+str(-m.options.objfcnval))
```

This works but it only works when I add `m.Maximize` inside the for loop. Running the same without the `m.Maximize` inside the loop produces wrong result(like below). The problem is the binary selector `yb`. When `yb = [0,1,0]` => `y=2`, the summation bound would be i=0 to 2. But I am not able to get this behaviour. I cannot run the for loop with `range(y)` because it is a GKVariable and also it changes the equation size as variable values change.

```python
obj = m.exp(x) + x**0/yf[0]
for j in range(1,len(yb)+1):
    obj += x**j/yf[j]*yb[j-1] # It non-zero only when yb[j-1]=1 and misses the values before that.
#Without it I'm computing the entire bound everytime and changing yb has no impact.
m.Maximize(obj)
```

In the working solution, how does Gekko give me the correct result? How to reproduce this behaviour, when the function is a constraint as below (i.e. without using `m.maximize` inside the for loop)? Thank you.

[image]

Edit:
(Modified the above python code). The below figure illustrates the problem. Consider `yb=[0,1,0]` => `y=2`. So the summation should to stop at `i=0 to 1`

[image]

I can do this easily if `x` and `yb` were normal lists then I could get the expected results from below.

```python
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import factorial

x = 3
yb = [0,1,0]
y = np.sum([yb[i]*(i+1) for i in range(3)])
yf = factorial(np.linspace(0,len(yb),len(yb)+1))
obj = np.exp(x)
for j in range(0,y):
    obj += x**j/yf[j] 
print(obj)
```

If I don't want the final equation size to change with the variable, I can do the below.

```python
x = 3
yb = [0,1,0]
y = np.sum([yb[i]*(i+1) for i in range(3)])
yf = factorial(np.linspace(0,len(yb),len(yb)+1))
obj = np.exp(x)
for i in range(0,y):
    yb[i] = 1
for j in range(0,len(yb)):
    obj += (x**j/yf[j]) * yb[j]
print(obj)
```

I cannot do both the option with Gekko because `x` and `yb` are GKVariable (design variable) and cannot be interpreted as an integer (i.e) `range(y)` doesn't work. Is there any workaround for this ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there aren't any responses, I'm sharing the workaround that I came up with. It probably is not an efficient way of doing it but it works.

```python
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
x = m.sos1([1,2,3])
yb = m.Array(m.Var,3,lb=0,ub=1,integer=True)
m.Equation(m.sum(yb)==1)
y = m.sum([yb[i]*(i+1) for i in range(3)])
#m.Equation(m.sum([yb[i]*(i+1) for i in range(3)])<2)
yf = factorial(np.linspace(0,len(yb),len(yb)+1))
obj = m.exp(x) + x**0/yf[0]
obj_temp=[]
for j in range(1,len(yb)+1):
    obj_temp.append(x**j/yf[j])
    for k in range(j):
        obj+= obj_temp[k] * yb[j-1]
m.Maximize(obj)        
m.solve()
print('x='+str(x.value[0]))
print('y='+str(y.value[0]))
print('Objective='+str(-m.options.objfcnval))
```

However, I don't know how Gekko replicates this additional `for loop` internally and why it only works when the summation function is an objective (`m.Maximze`) and fails when it is a constraint(`m.Equation`).